# Disable button after use | Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wrote this in my `index.js` to reply when a button is pressed and then disable it.

```
client.on("interactionCreate",  async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isButton()) {
    if (interaction.customId === "yes") {
      const owner_role = await db.get(`Owner-${interaction.guild.id}`);

      if (!owner_role) {
        return interaction.reply({ content: `:no: The server's owner haven't set up the bot yet. Please contact them.`, ephemeral: true })
      };

      if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(owner_role)) {
        return interaction.reply({ content: ":no: You don't have permission to use this command.", ephemeral: true })
      };

      interaction.reply(`This suggestion has been approved by ${interaction.user}.`)

      // Disable the button

    }
```

The only thing that I don't know, is how I disable the button.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new `MessageActionRow` with a new `MessageButton` and disable it with `setDisabled(true)`

```
  await interaction.reply(`This suggestion has been approved by ${interaction.user}.`);

  const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
      new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('customId')
        .setLabel('some label')
        .setDisabled(true)
    );

  await interaction.editReply({ components: [row] });
```